# How can I put the current thread to sleep?

Tags: rust, sleep

There is so much outdated information, it is really hard to find out how to sleep. I'd like something similar to this Java code:

```
Thread.sleep(4000);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Updated answer**

This is the updated code for the current Rust version:

```
use std::time::Duration;
use std::thread::sleep;

fn main() {
    sleep(Duration::from_millis(2));
}
```

Rust play url: http://is.gd/U7Oyip

**Old answer pre-1.0**

According the pull request https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/23330 the feature that will replace the old `std::old_io::timer::sleep` is the new `std::thread::sleep`.

Pull request description on GitHub:

> This function is the current replacement for std::old_io::timer which
>   will soon be deprecated. This function is unstable and has its own
>   feature gate as it does not yet have an RFC nor has it existed for
>   very long.

Code example:

```
#![feature(std_misc, thread_sleep)]

use std::time::Duration;
use std::thread::sleep;

fn main() {
    sleep(Duration::milliseconds(2));
}
```

This uses [`sleep`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.sleep.html) and [`Duration`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/duration/struct.Duration.html), which are currently behind the feature gates of `thread_sleep` and `std_misc`, respectively.

Comment: error: #[feature] may not be used on the stable release channel. A great many wonderful APIs are unlocked using #[feature] but if you download Rust from the prominent web sites you can't use #[feature].

Answer (score 83):

#### Rust 1.4+

[`Duration`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Duration.html) and [`sleep`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.sleep.html) have returned and are stable!

```rust
use std::{thread, time::Duration};

fn main() {
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(4000));
}
```

You could also use `Duration::from_secs(4)`, which might be more obvious in this case.

The solution below for 1.0 will continue to work if you prefer it, due to the nature of semantic versioning.

#### Rust 1.0+

Duration wasn't made stable in time for 1.0, so there's a new function in town - [`thread::sleep_ms`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.sleep_ms.html):

```rust
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    thread::sleep_ms(4000);
}
```