# How to do a typewriter effect in rust

Tags: rust

So I'm attempting to learn the basics of rust; and I thought a good way of doing that might be to convert an old python program of mine to rust! I was wondering if there was any way to get a typewriter effect. As it plays a key role in the program.

Here's the old python code

```
def scroll(str):


  for letter in str:
    sys.stdout.write(letter)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.075)
```

now that let me do something along the lines of

```
time.sleep(.5)
scroll("But there's no sense crying over every mistake.\n")
scroll("You just keep on trying till you run out of cake.\n")
scroll("And the Science gets done.\n")
scroll("And you make a neat gun.\n")
scroll("For the people who are still alive.\n")
time.sleep(1)
```

Essentially replace the print command with the keyword "scroll" I don't expect it to be that easy in rust; but as long as there's some method I can use to slowly print text letter by letter I'll be happy.

I've attempted searching online but there's not much that I can find in regards to this specific thing; I've been able to get every other component I need working for the program; from playing audio to clearing the terminal.

Please keep the explanations simple as I'm new to programming as a whole, but only started my Rust journey about an hour ago.

Comment: `I've attempted searching online but there's not much that I can find in regards to this specific thing`, I think you should check on simple things like: `how to print a character?`, `how to sleep?`, `how to loop?`, otherwise it should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and straight forward translation:

```rust
use std::io::Write;

fn scroll(s: &str) {
    for c in s.chars() {
        print!("{c}");
        std::io::stdout().flush().expect("Flushing to succeed");
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(75));
    }
}

fn main() {
    scroll("But there's no sense crying over every mistake.\n");
    scroll("You just keep on trying till you run out of cake.\n");
    scroll("And the Science gets done.\n");
    scroll("And you make a neat gun.\n");
    scroll("For the people who are still alive.\n");
}
```

You can check how it works from this other answers:

- [How to get chars from a `&str` or `String`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47829753/1695172)
- [How to flush stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40392936/1695172)
- [How to put a thread to sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28953618/1695172)

Comment: Thanks a ton this is exactly what I had in mind!